# Convert to upper case when does not match particular strings in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Need to convert to upper case when the column values does not match particular string else should be same source value in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'freq': ['/Weekly/', '/ad/','/Annual/', '/aB/'],
                         'typ': ['TEST', 'A','TEST2', 'YYYY'],                                    
                        'category': ['ACC', 'T','TEST3', 'ZZZZ'],
                        'id': ['1', '2','3', '4']})
Code:
df['tgt'] = np.where((df[~df.freq.str.startswith(('/Wee','/Ann'))],df['freq'].astype(str).str.upper(),df['freq']))

Expected output: 
    freq       typ          category    id   tgt 
0   /Weekly/    TEST          ACC       1   /Weekly/
1   /ad/        A             T         2   /AD/
2   /Annual/    TEST2         TEST3     3   /Annual
3   /aB/        YYYY          ZZZZ      4   /AB/
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake in the initial code is related to the usage of `np.where`. The condition for the function should be passed as the first argument, but in the original code, it was applied to the DataFrame itself. To fix this, you need to modify the code by replacing `df[~df.freq.str.startswith(('/Wee','/Ann'))]` with `~df['freq'].str.startswith(('/Wee', '/Ann'))`.

So here's the full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'freq': ['/Weekly/', '/ad/','/Annual/', '/aB/'],
                         'typ': ['TEST', 'A','TEST2', 'YYYY'],                                    
                        'category': ['ACC', 'T','TEST3', 'ZZZZ'],
                        'id': ['1', '2','3', '4']})

df['tgt'] = np.where(
    ~df['freq'].str.startswith(('/Wee', '/Ann')), 
    df['freq'].astype(str).str.upper(), 
    df['freq']
)
```

Additionally, in my opinion, you can directly use `df['freq'].str.upper()` instead of converting it to a string using `astype(str).str.upper()`.

Answer (score 0):

With [`df.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df['tgt'] = df['freq'].where(df['freq'].str.startswith(('/Wee','/Ann')), df['freq'].str.upper())
```

---

```
       freq    typ category id       tgt
0  /Weekly/   TEST      ACC  1  /Weekly/
1      /ad/      A        T  2      /AD/
2  /Annual/  TEST2    TEST3  3  /Annual/
3      /aB/   YYYY     ZZZZ  4      /AB/
```

Comment: A small change , how can we get upper - (df['typ'].str.upper())) when not matching  /Wee and /Ann else the actual value of df['typ'] instead of freq in above results